# Gradle Profile Shows Dependency Resolution for Other Variants

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a multi-module build that has multiple variants, for example modules App, LibA and LibB and variants release, debug, and tester.  When I run a build profile for the tester variant, I see under dependency resolution that the following are running:

```
App:releaseCompileClasspath
App:releaseRuntimeClasspath
App:releaseImplementationDependenciesMetadata
App:releaseRuntimeOnlyDependenciesMetadata
App:releaseAnnotationProcessorClasspath
App:releaseApiDependenciesMetadata
App:releaseCompileOnly
App:releaseCompileOnlyDependenciesMetadata
```

These extra tasks are slowing down my build, is there any reason they are running or any way to disable them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voila! This exact scenario has been targeted in Android Studio 3.3!

Android Studio 3.3 now supports **Single-variant project sync!**

As per the [latest release notes for Android Studio 3.3](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#single-variant),

> Syncing your project with your build configuration is an important step in letting Android Studio understand how your project is structured. However, this process can be time-consuming for large projects. If your project uses multiple build variants, you can now optimize project syncs by limiting them to only the variant you have currently selected.

**Requirements:**

1. Android Studio 3.3 or higher
2. Android Gradle plugin 3.3.0 or higher

**Steps:**

Click File > Settings > Experimental > Gradle (Android Studio > Preferences > Experimental > Gradle on a Mac) and select the **Only sync the active variant** checkbox